# Realtek New Master Make Error parameters name queue high on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: make, realtek-wireless, ubuntu-make

I just shifted from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04, But My Wifi Signal is weak. Some times it is working fine then after few seconds it's signal is totally lost and after few seconds signal comes then after few seconds its totally gone it happens continously. When signal lost and i visit any website then it shows Internet not connected.
I have came accross a article : https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/

In this article, they said to run the make command. When i go to that directory and run **make** command then after few minute i got this error and the command is terminated :

```
alex@alexelsner:~/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic/build M=/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.o
/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.c: In function ‘_rtl92cu_init_chipN_one_out_ep_priority’:
/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.c:622:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  622 |  u16 uninitialized_var(value);
      |  ^~~
/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.c:626:3: error: ‘value’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  626 |   value = QUEUE_HIGH;
      |   ^~~~~
/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.c:626:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.c: In function ‘_rtl92cu_init_chipN_two_out_ep_priority’:
/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.c:648:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  648 |  u16 uninitialized_var(valueHi);
      |  ^~~
/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.c:649:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  649 |  u16 uninitialized_var(valueLow);
      |  ^~~
/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.c:653:3: error: ‘valueHi’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  653 |   valueHi = QUEUE_HIGH;
      |   ^~~~~~~
/home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.c:654:3: error: ‘valueLow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  654 |   valueLow = QUEUE_LOW;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu/hw.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:518: /home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/rtl8192cu] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1848: /home/alex/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-27-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:76: all] Error 2
alex@alexelsner:~/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master$
```

Please someone help me, i am facing too much issues.

Comment: You missed one fundamental detail: What you downloaded is for kernels 5.8 or older and you should've followed the instructions for 5.11 or newer, regardless of the Ubuntu release. Ubuntu 20.04 runs 5.11 now.

Comment: @ChanganAuto do you know any solution to the problem? my wifi keeps disconnecting

Comment: The previous comment was to make you understand you've followed the wrong part of that guide. That should be obvious because if it works, albeit not in the ideal conditions, you already have a driver installed, no need to install another. You can try it from the part "For Ubuntu 21.04 (kernel 5.11) and above" forwards only. Whether or not it'll make a difference you tell us. I would try it anyway but also check the **router** and make sure the recommended options are set: WPA2-AES only, no WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP encryption.